# Ruby on Rails: switching from rails 2.3.8 to 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my env I require 3.0.3

but when I script/server

I get this: `can't activate rails (= 2.3.8, runtime) for [], already activated rails-3.0.3`

I don't want it to activate 2.3.8.. =\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 3.x doesn't use `script/server` anymore - you should run your server with `rails server` or `rails s`. You can delete all the files from `script`, except for `script\rails`.

Plus, you no longer specify your Rails version in environment.rb (if that's what you mean by "env"). All gems and their versions are specified in your `Gemfile`.

Did you follow a guide like [Upgrading to Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1)? It's not enough to just change the Rails version in `evironment.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

The command to run the server in Rails 3 is `rails server`. What happens if you run that?

Comment: I get the usage / help stuff.

Comment: You need to indicate where your rails project is located at. Are you starting the server from the right directory?

Comment: yep. I have cd'd into my project directory and thats what rails server does. gives me the "this is how you use this" message

Comment: I would suggest you try one of these: a) uninstall Rails 2 or b) install RVM (rvm.beginrescueend.com) to have a separate verion of ruby with only one rails gem (for version 3)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 uses

```
rails server
```

command instead of

```
ruby script/server
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `environment.rb` to make sure that you're not specifying rails 2.3.8 explicitly.  If you are then you need to make sure you've upgraded to bundler properly.

My suggestion is to generate an empty rails 3 project and look at how the generated files and make sure your app looks similar.